# or_where clause not working in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i used where and  or_where clause in this function.but the or_where clause is not working.instead of what i need to change here.if i hide or_where condition its working.

```
public function logincheck()
{
$this->load->database();
$mobile=$this->input->post('mobile');//rollno or mobile

 $status='1';
$user_type='student';
$password=$this->input->post('password');

$this->db->select('*')->from('student_creation')
->join('login','student_creation.student_id=login.login_id')
->where('login.user_type',$user_type)
->where('login.password',$password)
->where('student_creation.alternativemobile',$mobile)
->or_where('student_creation.rollno',$mobile);
 //$this->db->or_where('student_creation.alternativemobile',$mobile);

$query = $this->db->get();
//$rowcount = $query->num_rows();  
if($query->num_rows()==1)
{
$row=$query->row();

$data=array(
        'rollno'=>$row->rollno,
        'student_id'=>$row->student_id,
        'alternativemobile'=>$row->alternativemobile,
        'login_id'=>$row->login_id,
        'password'=>$row->password,
        'user_type'=>'student',
        'loginchecks'=>true
);


$this->session->set_userdata($data);
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: what is the CI version you are using?

Comment: im using 3.0.1 version

Comment: You can write your own clauses manually:

$where = "name='Joe' AND status='boss' OR status='active'";
$this->db->where($where);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use multiple `where` and `or_where` like you have used.

If your CI version is 3 or above, then you can use `query-grouping` function to achieve this. check this link https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping

Comment: ->where("(student_creation.alternativemobile = $mobile OR student_creation.rollno = $mobile)", null, false);

Comment: SELECT * FROM `student_creation` JOIN `login` ON `student_creation`.`student_id`=`login`.`login_id` WHERE `login`.`user_type` = 'student' AND `login`.`password` = '123' AND (login.parent_mobile = STROLL001 || student_creation.rollno = STROLL001)

Comment: i enter the mobile no means its logged in.but the rollno is  not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('student_creation')
->join('login','student_creation.student_id=login.login_id')
->where('login.user_type',$user_type)
->where('login.password',$password)
->where("(student_creation.alternativemobile = ".(int)$mobile." OR student_creation.rollno = '$mobile' )", null, false);
```

Comment: what is the datatype of `rollno` field in phpmyadmin   ?? , i mean what type of field is it  `int` or `varchar` ???

Comment: i given varchar only

Comment: Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'STROLL001' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM `student_creation` JOIN `login` ON `student_creation`.`student_id`=`login`.`login_id` WHERE `login`.`user_type` = 'student' AND `login`.`password` = '123' AND (student_creation.alternativemobile = STROLL001 OR student_creation.rollno = 'STROLL001' )

Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/management/application/models/Studentlogin_model.php

Line Number: 54

Comment: @kailashkumar is it working now  ?? if it is mark it as answer by clicking `tick mark` on the left hand side right under '0'... :)